# Performance issue due to include statement in Entity Framework

Tags: performance, entity-framework, linq, join, include

I have a performance issue with the API. It is due to retrieving data from multiple tables like below

Example:

```
Users.Include(x => x.UsersAdditionInfo)
     .Include(x => x.UserRoles)
     .Include(x => x.Location)
```

Note: each of these tables contains nearly (1,50,000) records except location table.

I have used joins instead of `.Include` then also facing the same performance issues.

Example:

```
from ub in users
join ua in UserAdditionalInfo on ub.Id equals ua.UserId
join ur in UserRoles on ub.Id equals ur.UserId
join urs in userRoles on ur.RoleId equals urs.Id
join l in Location on ub.LocationId equals l.Id
into leftLocation
from location in leftLocation.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Kindly suggest for better alternative ways to query in multiple tables

Comment: if query computation is no issue (which I assume is not, though a high number of includes can make the query computation quite heavy), then you should try to decrease the number of records returned / number of queries actually executed. What are you doing with these IQueryables?

Answer (score 0):

If your EDMX is probably configured, you don't have to join yourself.
Can't you just do

```
Users.Select(x=> new { 
                   UserRoles = x.UserRoles, 
                   UserAdditionInfo = x.UserAdditionInfo, 
                   Location = x.Location })
```

and so on?

(I've fudged your schema a bit but hopefully you get my point)

Also, if this is common, you could also always create a view in SQL Server and add it in EDMX

Comment: Hi Thanks! We don't use edmx file in our project. we are following code first approach.